# Covariance Matrix for LDA

Tags: machine-learning, covariance

I have two classes of data:

$X = (3,2),(2,3),(1,2),(2,1),(-2,-1),(-1,-2),(-3,-2),(-2,-3)$

$Y = 1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0$

Here, $Y$ is a binary label for each corresponding value of $X$. For example, the label for $X_1=(3,2)$ is $1$.

The task is to compute a covariance matrix for LDA. For this, we'll need the means:

$\mu_{Y_1}= \frac{1}{4}((3,2)+(2,3)+(1,2)+(2,1))=(2,2)$
$\mu_{Y_0}= \frac{1}{4}((-3,-2)+(-2,-3)+(-1,-2)+(-2,-1))=(-2,-2)$

So far, so good. The formula for each entry in the covariance matrix is:
$$ \hat \lambda_{d,d} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i(X_{i,d}-\mu_{d,k})(X_{i,d'}-\mu_{d',k}) $$

The differences $(X_{i,d}-\mu_{d,k})$ for each class $k$ are given by:

$\delta_{Y_1}= (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1))$

$\delta_{Y_0}= (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1))$

At this point I'm unclear how to proceed. The solution is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $$

But I'm unsure how to arrive at this given that the inputs are cartesian coordinates. For instance, the diagonals should represent the variances of each class, but how is a variance of $\frac{1}{2}$ computed in this case?